# How do I remove rounded border around menu popup?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-menu

My app has a menu popup when you click the three dots on the top right of the screen. For some reason, there is a rounded border around the menu items. I have looked at other android apps and they do not have this border. I used the basic activity template on Android Studio to get the menu.

[Weird border around menu, shown more clearly by clicking an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ85k.png)

I looked at the preview for the menu xml file, and there is no border.

[Popup as shown in xml preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XAHF.png)

How can I remove this border?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
// set your activity style add popup style 
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle" >@style/myPopupMenu</item>
// your popup style in "style.xml"
<style name="myPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/shape_menu</item>
</style>

// "shape_menu" drawable in your "drawable/shape_menu.xml", radius is rounded border
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```